# Damaged passport - docs required

Tags: indian-citizens, india, budget, passport-renewals

Are there extra charges for passport re-issuance in case of a damaged passport? The book got detached from cover, that's all.

For Non-ECR, where to find the seal? Can't see in my passport. 
Hope overseas stay > 3yrs should suffice as we don't have other docs at hand presently.

Comment: What seal? What does your other questions have to do with renewing your passport?

Comment: Seal for Non-ECR: Guess these days no such seal on the passport itself.   
For obtaining Non-ECR passport, need to know what documentation is required considering I don't have education certs on hand currently.   
Overall, wanted to know whether Tatkaal is must for cases where passport has not been damaged beyond recognition

Comment: So, you have two questions? Cost of a new passport, and something about how to get a seal? Can you re-write your question and choose a better title to make it easier to understand? I can't help you as I don't understand the question.